# HTML Javascript - Get all elements with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using the `waterwheel-carousel` image slider located [here](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel). I would like to have multiple carousels on one page.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<script>
    // load carousel
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#waterwheel-carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
            separation: 90,
            separationMultiplier: 0.2,
            horizonOffsetMultiplier: 1
        });
    });
</script>
.
.
.
<div id="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>     

<div id="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>  

<div id="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Projects page carousel(s) */
#waterwheel-carousel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 216px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#waterwheel-carousel img {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

The issue is that only the first `#waterwheel-carousel` will load. The other two do not. I did some research and it seems like it may only be returning the first element with that id. So I have tried a different approach on my `$(document).ready(..` function, adding `class="waterwheel-carousel"` to each `div`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var allElements = $(document).getElementsByClassName("waterwheel-carousel");
      for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
          var currentElement = allElements[i];
          currentElement.waterwheelCarousel({
              separation: 90,
              separationMultiplier: 0.2,
              horizonOffsetMultiplier: 1
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

But then they **all** fail to load.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: use class not id - id will only find first instance - read difference between classes and ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. [see](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Instead of id use class to get all element

```
<script>
    // load carousel
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".waterwheel-carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
            separation: 90,
            separationMultiplier: 0.2,
            horizonOffsetMultiplier: 1
        });
    });
</script>
.
.
.
<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>     

<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>  

<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
  <img src="" alt="one">
  <img src="" alt="two">
  <img src="" alt="three">
  <img src="" alt="four">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what classes are for, IDs are unique. Which means that each element in the document must have a different ID.

Modify your HTML:

```
<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
<img src="" alt="one">
<img src="" alt="two">
<img src="" alt="three">
<img src="" alt="four">
</div>     

<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
<img src="" alt="one">
<img src="" alt="two">
<img src="" alt="three">
<img src="" alt="four">
</div>  

<div class="waterwheel-carousel">
<img src="" alt="one">
<img src="" alt="two">
<img src="" alt="three">
<img src="" alt="four">
</div>
```

and you're good to go.